# Will imported mesh from CAD application with bad topology be problematic for texturing/materials?

Tags: mesh, vertices

I am currently doing my first own project in Blender (rendering a PCB). The object I am using is an obj export from a PCB design software. This is the mesh:

[image]

As you can see the faces and vertices are not uniform or evenly spaced. Will that be a problem when it comes to texturing/ using materials? If so, how can I fix this mesh? Should I just add more verticies and try to space them evenly? Is there a way to do it fast/automated (for bigger objects later on)?

Comment: it depends on how you want to project your texture, etc, you can probably keep your curent topology

Comment: It could be ok for texturing/materials, it won't be ok for smooth shading or change in the geometry (subsurf, bevel, ...).

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Messy topology may in some cases affect how easy it is to select edges to be marked as seams for UV unwrapping. It doesn't seem to be a huge deal in this case.
- It may affect UV unwrapping as well, especially if there are bits of non-manifold geometry or unconnected geometry. In this case, it doesn't seem to be too bad
- Messy geometry will affect bevels if you chose to make them. They are not part of materials, but since bevels usually catch highlights it affects visual aspect of the model a lot. In your case you might be able to get away with it even if you decide to make bevels, since the part seems to be relatively simple. You could try to disable/enable Loop Slide for bevels to see how it works better. It's also possible to simulate bevels in the shader without actual beveled geometry which is very useful in precisely cases like this.

[image]

[image]

- You may have problems with smooth shading if you need it. There may be various artefacts:

[image]

You may not need smooth shading here, or could use Auto Smooth.

If those are not particularly big problems in your situation, you don't need to worry.